# Questions About Asp.NET and IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, appdomain

**Can you help me thru these questions :**

1. Application Pool may contain multiple worker processes (w3wp.exe) ?
2. Application Pool may contain multiple Asp.NET Applications ?
3. Asp.NET assigns one ThreadPool per AppDomain ?
4. One AppDomain only contain one Web Application Instance but Application can contain multiple AppDomains ?

Can you answer those questions ? and if you have more to add, please provide them as well.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit :** These questions are related to IIS 6x or higher, in which App Domains are available.

Comment: Please add which version of IIS and ASP.NET.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) yes

2) yes, assuming they are all using the same .Net Framework version (can't run 1.x and 2.0 apps in same app pool)

3) it's supposed to be one per process.

4) yes

Comment: re: question 3.  Your answer is correct, if you recognize that ... Splitting hairs ... It is .NET that provides the ThreadPool, not ASP.NET.

Comment: Is there anything you can add you think it would be good to learn for people when they read your post ? Thank you.